# Ruby on Rails Incorrect Primary Key Names

Tags: mysql, ruby, aptana, radrails

I'm using RadRails to create my MYSQL database tables.  This is migration task:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :eventname
      t.string :evententryurl
      t.string :eventurl

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :events
  end
end
```

I then run a db:migrate Rake task.  This creates the following fields within the database table:

```
id
eventname
evententryurl
eventurl
```

OK, so far.  The problem I have is when I run the application and go to http://localhost/events/new  the application is looking for eventid as it's primary key, not id.  How can I change my migration task so that it automatically puts eventid into the database as the primary key?

Comment: Show an example of your model for the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to override the default primary key name of `id` in the migration with `eventid`.  I assume the application is looking for `eventid` instead of `id` because you used `set_primary_key :eventid` in the model.

Here's what you need:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table

> :primary_key The name of the primary
>   key, if one is to be added
>   automatically. Defaults to id. If :id
>   is false this option is ignored.
>
> Also note that this just sets the
>   primary key in the table. You
>   additionally need to configure the
>   primary key in the model via the
>   set_primary_key macro. Models do NOT
>   auto-detect the primary key from their
>   table definition.